# Элементы ActionBar в Gmail

Tags: actionbar, android, java, gmail

Здравствуйте!

Возникла проблема с элементом в ActionBar помеченным как **'**`android:showAsAction="never"`**'** - этот элемент создается когда нет кнопки `menu` у смартфона.

ab_notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/ab_item_overview">
    </item>
</menu>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App</string>
    <string name="ab_item_notifications">Notifications</string>
</resources>
```

NotificationActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ab_notifications, menu);
    return true;
}
```

На планшете это выглядит так (у планшета нет кнопки `menu`):
[image]

На смартфоне это выглядит так (итем `Overview` появляется после нажатия кнопки `menu`):

[image]

**НО**, всё это фигня какая-то, так как приложение Gmail опять отличилось:

[image]

[image]

Как они сделали так, что на смартфоне кнопка `menu` не выводит ничего, а этот элемент всегда отображается в ActionBar?

Comment: можно сделать кастомную кнопку как вариант.   
А так у них есть мануал вроде как http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: @Andreich да, я пробовал сделать это через ImageButton, но не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBar на Android < 3.0 будет всегда показывать внизу.
android:showAsAction="never" означает, что этот элемент меню будет внутри "⋮".

Comment: @Anatoliy 

>android:showAsAction="never" означает, что этот элемент меню будет внутри "⋮".

Да, это я понял, вопрос стоит в том, как сделать элемент "⋮" всегда видимым, как это сделано в приложении Gmail?